# What keyboard layout should one switch to, for maximum typing speed?

Tags: keyboard, speed, layout, typing, qwerty

If this [link](http://patorjk.com/keyboard-layout-analyzer/) is to be believed, then colemak/capewell/arensito are the layouts that make the fingers move the least amount of distance over the keyboard.

It looks like Colemak is the best supported one of the three, and the most similar to QWERTY.

Does anyone here have experience with the former two layouts, I'd love to know how you went in switching, and what kind of a speed increase you saw?

Would it be worth switching to one of the former two, for an increase in typing speed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Think I'll stick with colemak](http://forum.colemak.com/viewtopic.php?id=42) -> for overall usage/support on various OS's -> and the fact that it is designed for normal keyboards (not kinetic). Speed difference won't be too great between the three, as colemak only generates a slight increase in finger movement.

Answer (score 0):

See [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1255/is-learning-the-dvorak-keyboard-layout-worth-the-trouble), and [this one over on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455525/is-the-switch-to-dvorak-worth-it).

And [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854/keyboard-layout) (which even mentions colemak), and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171597/dvorak-vs-qwerty).

The consensus seems to be that any speed increase is slight, and is only achieved after a lot of practice - and comes with costs that make teamwork slightly harder. However, people report less strain using colemak.

Comment: Dvorak is not a layout I wish to switch to. As it doesn't seem to be the most efficient.

Comment: This is only for my personal productivity - no teamwork.

Comment: report less strain using colemak. - Well yes, due to difference in finger travel distance. But I'd like to know which of the above 3 is the fastest? colemak/capewell/arensito?